# Whether location is nominal or ordinal in this case?

Tags: scales

I have a variable in my data 'location'. It has two categories: 'busy' and 'less busy'. Should I treat it as nominal or ordinal? 
I think it should be treated as ordinal.

Comment: It's binary (dichotomous, quantal, Boolean, indicator),  as e.g. coding busy as 1 and not busy as 0 would enable you to calculate means (the proportion busy), which may be as or more useful than having an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it's ordinal in that "less busy" is less than "busy" and there's no clear definition of how much less "less" is. On the other hand, with just two levels I'm not sure that it will make any practical difference.